# onActivityResult not getting result

Tags: android

I simply want to return the string with intent from a another activity but not getting that string in parent activity...though no error is shown.
for test purpose just want to show toast message on return of result..

here's the code of parent activity....

```
public class Login2 extends Activity {
     static final int REQ_CODE=0;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

      Button startButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
         public void onClick(View view)
         {          
          final TextView var=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errmsg);

          EditText usrnameobj = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_usename);
          EditText usrpassobj = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password); 
          String username = usrnameobj.getText().toString(); 
          String password = usrpassobj.getText().toString(); 

          Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AndroidXmlResource.class);
          i.putExtra("entry",username.toString() + password.toString());
          startActivityForResult(i,REQ_CODE);
         }  
         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

            {

          //if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) 
           {

                      //String res = data.getExtras().getString("result");
                     // TextView var=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errmsg);
                     // var.setVisibility(0);
                     // var.setText(res.toString());
                     // var.setText("called on act res");

                      Toast.makeText(Login2.this,"Hi! Bright Hub", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            }
        });
```

And here's the child activity that returns a result....

```
public class AndroidXmlResource extends Activity {

 //public String U="sudeep1";
 //public String P="donotlock1";
 public int Res;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  //setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras == null) {
   return;
  }
  String pass=extras.getString("entry");
  //String result= new String();
        //TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_test);

  try {
   String stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
   //myXmlContent.setText(pass.toString());
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
   if(stringXmlContent.equals(pass))
   {

    returnIntent.putExtra("result","valid Login");
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);   
       super.finish();

   }
   else
   {
    returnIntent.putExtra("result","Invalid Login");
       setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);   
       super.finish();

   }


  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }

    private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {

     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
     Resources res = activity.getResources();
     XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
     xpp.next();
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
     {
      int c=1;
      if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
      {
       //stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");
      }
      else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
      {
       //stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());

      }
      else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
      {
       //stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
      }
      else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
      {
       //stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: "+xpp.getText());
       //extra

       { String t=xpp.getText().toString();

         stringBuffer.append(t.toString());      

       }       
      }

      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
     //stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
     return stringBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: Please format the code in a way you can read it... :/

Comment: Thanks for the format @Cristian!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do not have android:noHistory="true" attribute for  element.

Answer (score 1):

in your parent activity, you should be doing this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQ_CODE) 
   {

    String res = data.getExtras().getString("result");
    Toast.makeText(Login2.this,"Hi! Bright Hub: "+res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 }
```

Which you're already using.

what does `super.finish()` do?
why not `this.finish()` ??

Comment: thx aman i tried but did not make any diff, also used this.finish() but all in vain :( ----any hints..

Comment: Can you put your code on gist.github.com, or ur project somewhere, if that's okay, for us to check!?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please put `@Override onActivityResult()` and another one in `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)`?

Make sure this in child activity.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have not added this line **`android:launchMode="singleInstance|singleTask"`**  in **`menifest.xml`** where you have declared your activty .If you have added, remove this for getting result on `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution that I found was to replace the startActivityForResult functionality by storing the result into the shared preferences and loading them later in onResume. Check the full discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16837679/2436683).